# How can I add an underbrace in this TikZ picture matrix of maths nodes?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-matrix

I have the current tikz picture and would like to add a underbrace between the 2nd and 3rd row at the location unidentified by the 2 arrows pointing down.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing, matrix, arrows}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=angle 90]
                \matrix(a)[matrix of math nodes,
                column sep=-5pt,
        %       row sep=-5pt,
                text height=1ex]
                { y = & x^2 & -5x & +6 & \qquad & & & \frac{1}{2}(-5)=\frac{-5}{2} \\
                y = & x^2 &  -5x &+\frac{25}{4} & - \frac{25}{4}&+6 & \qquad & & \left(\frac{-5}{2}\right)^2=\frac{25}{4} \\
                &  &  & \hspace{1pt} & \\
                y=& (x &-&\frac{5}{2}&)^2 -\frac{1}{4} &\\};
                \path[->](a-2-9) edge [bend left=20] (a-2-4);
                \path[->](a-2-9) edge [bend left=20] (a-2-5);
                \path[->](a-1-8) edge [bend left=50] (a-4-4);
                \path[->](a-2-2) edge [out=270,in=90] (a-4-3);
                \path[->](a-2-3) edge [out=270,in=90] (a-4-3);               
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

In the following figure, I want to change the arrows next to the red into an underbrace:

[image: schematic target]

Comment: Where exactly? "between the 2nd and 3rd row at the location unidentified by the 2 arrows pointing down" confuses me so much. How long should this underbrace be? Can you add an image of the desired output?

Comment: In the figure here: http://i.stack.imgur.com/R0Nuv.png

I want to change the arrows next to the red into an underbrace. Hope this better explains what i am trying to say.

Comment: Better, thanks, although I still am not sure. Do my answers below do what you want?

Answer (score 7):

Nothing special here, since you have access to the anchors for the nodes in the matrix, so you simply need

```
\draw[red,decorate,decoration={brace,mirror,raise=-2pt}]
  ([xshift=3pt]a-2-2.south west) -- ([xshift=-5pt]a-2-3.south east);
```

or

```
\draw[red,decorate,decoration={brace,mirror,raise=-2pt}]
  ([xshift=3pt]a-2-2.south west) -- ([xshift=-4pt]{a-2-3.south east|-a-2-2.south west});
```

to guarantee that the brace is completely horizontal.

The complete code (I did some other optional changes):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing, matrix, arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=angle 90]
\matrix (a) [
  matrix of math nodes,
  column sep=-5pt,
  %row sep=-5pt,
  text height=1ex
]
{
   y = & x^2 & -5x & +6 & \qquad & & & \frac{1}{2}(-5)=\frac{-5}{2} \\
   y = & x^2 &  -5x &+\frac{25}{4} & - \frac{25}{4}&+6 & \qquad 
     & & \left(\frac{-5}{2}\right)^2=\frac{25}{4} \\
  & & & & \\[8pt]
  y=& (x &-&\frac{5}{2})^2 & -\frac{1}{4} &\\
};

\path[->]
  (a-2-9) edge [bend left=20] (a-2-4)
  (a-2-9) edge [bend left=20] (a-2-5)
  (a-1-8) edge [bend left=50] (a-4-4)
  (a-2-2) edge [out=270,in=90] (a-4-3)
  (a-2-3) edge [out=270,in=90] (a-4-3);               
\draw[red,decorate,decoration={brace,mirror,raise=-2pt}]
  ([xshift=3pt]a-2-2.south west) -- ([xshift=-4pt]{a-2-3.south east|-a-2-2.south west});
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice, however, that the spacing in the above solution is wrong and inconsistent (looking closely around the operators you'll see this). I propose you an alternative approach. Use `align*` (or `alignat*`) from `amsmath` to write the equation and then TikZ with the help of the `tikzmark` library to place some marks later used to draw the brace and the arrows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing, matrix, arrows,tikzmark}

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
y &= x^2 -5x +6 & -5\Bigl(\tikzmark{startc}\frac{1}{2}\Bigr) &= \frac{-5}{2} \\[10pt]
y &= \tikzmark{starta}x^2 - 5x\tikzmark{enda} + \frac{25}{\tikzmark{endbi}4} 
  - \frac{25}{\tikzmark{endbii}4} +6 & \Bigl(\frac{-5}{2}\Bigr)^2 
  &= \tikzmark{startb}\frac{25}{4} \\[10pt]
y &= \Bigl(x  - \frac{5}{\tikzmark{endc}2} \Bigr)^2 -\frac{1}{4}
\end{align*}

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw[red,decorate,decoration={brace,mirror,raise=2pt}]
  (pic cs:starta) -- (pic cs:enda);
\path[->]
  (pic cs:startb) edge [bend left=20] ([shift={(5pt,-3pt)}]pic cs:endbi)
  (pic cs:startb) edge [bend left=20] ([shift={(5pt,-3pt)}]pic cs:endbii)
  ([shift={(5pt,-8pt)}]pic cs:startc) edge [bend left=20] ([shift={(5pt,-3pt)}]pic cs:endc);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]